# Issue with javax.transation.SystemException with Neo4j

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

It seems in my project I am getting an exception: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException`

Anyway I have the following Maven dependency for the transaction:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also have jar, as pulled in by Maven, being `javax.transation:jta:1.1`

This is occurring when I am using Neo4j and attempt to create a graphDatabaseFactory:

```
graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

where `DB_PATH = "/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/neo4j/2.0.1/libexec/data/graph.db"`

Any help as to how to resolve this exception would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maven downloads the necessary jars to compile your code. But, it does not embed those dependency jars into your project jar. So you have to add the folder of dependency jars into your CLASSPATH before running your own jar. You can solve this issue by either embedding those dependencies into your jar by using the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) or by adding the folder of downloaded dependencies into you classpath in your generated manifest.xml file by using [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html). First way may result in a large jar so it is better to alter manifest.xml file.